# Connect exception after notifyObservers

Tags: java, model-view-controller, rmi, swingx

I'm getting this error:

> Error al notificar: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.6; nested
>   exception is:     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

After I try to notify the remoteObservers, in this case being a controller.

Here is some part of the code.
This is from the Server:

```
public void notificarObservadores(Object aux) throws RemoteException{
         for(IRemoteObserver o: colObservadores){
             try {
                 o.update(this, aux);
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error al notificar: " + ex.getMessage());
                colObservadores.remove(this);
                System.out.println("Eliminado observer remoto no conectable");
            }

     }
 }
```

And this from the controller in the client:

```
public class ControladorMesa extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRemoteObserver,ActionListener{
    private IFachadaServidor servidor;
    private iFrmMesa formulario;
    public ControladorMesa(IFachadaServidor servidor, iFrmMesa frm) throws RemoteException{
        this.servidor = servidor;
        this.formulario = frm;
        this.servidor.agregarObservador(this);
        this.formulario.setController(this);
        this.formulario.setListaProductos(servidor.obtenerProductos());
    }
    @Override
    public void update(IFachadaServidor fachada, Object aux) throws RemoteException {
        this.formulario.setListaProductosgregados(fachada.ProductosAgregados(this.formulario.getMesa()));
    }
```

Comment: Your error simply relates to not being able to connect to the server at the TCP level. The code is irrelevant. Try something simple. Have a look at the server with `netstat` or similar to see if it really has a listener on the right host and port. From the client machine, try to `telnet` to the server host and port.

Comment: But the client is connected with the server until the server request for update.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline i can add objects and all, but when i need to get the list from the server via Observer pattern i get tgat exception.

Comment: Oh, is this a callback from the server to the client. IIRC, RMI is summetric, so this will require the "client" to act a server and the "server" to act as a client at the TCP level.

Comment: And what woudl be the solution?

Comment: First use `netstat` and `telnet` to check whether the connection should be possible and which end the problem is.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Well it was teh firewall all along. I turn it off and worked, maybe im missing some code to grant permission or something. Thx for the quick answers